# i have a csv file with locations i need to move s3 files to new locations

Tags: bash, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am interested in loading my data into AWS ATHENA DB

my data is compartmentalized by source_video, and in each we have 11 csv files that represent 11 tables referencing this data

ATHENA wants to load by table and not by source_video

for this i have to move these files to folders based on table name and not source_video.

I am fluent in python and bash
i know how to use the aws cli

i wish to know if there is maybe an easier way than running 4Million+ mv commands and executing them in different processes in parallel on several machines

I have a csv file that has locations of files located as children of the source_video they were created for:

I have 400,000+ source_video locations
I have 11 files in each source_video location

i.e.

```
+source_video1
- 11 files by type
+source_video2
- 11 files by type
+source_video3
- 11 files by type
.
.
+source_video400,000+
- 11 files by type
```

I wish to move them to 11 folders with 400,000+ files in each folder type

fields: videoName, CClocation, identityLocation, TAGTAskslocation, M2Location
and other locations ....

Below is an example of 2 rows of data:

```
 pj1/09/11/09/S1/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi,
 S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_CCsidentities.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_CCsTAGtasks.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_AL1CCs2data.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_AL1CCs2extendeddata.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_AL1CCsdata.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_CCsALGsruns.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_Cg1CCsdata.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_Cg1CCfeat.csv, s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1_1021866/S1_IBM2MP_0353_00070280_DVR1.avi_CCsidentitiestaggers.csv
 pj1/09/11/09/S1/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi,
 S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_CCsidentities.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_CCsTAGtasks.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_AL1CCs2data.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_AL1CCs2extendeddata.csv, s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_AL1CCsdata.csv, s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_CCsALGsruns.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_Cg1CCsdata.csv, s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_Cg1CCfeat.csv,
 s3:/bucket1/DB2/pj1/09/11/09/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1_307638/S1_IBM2MP_0443_00070380_DVR1.avi_CCsidentitiestaggers.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Athena expects all files related to one table to be located in one directory, or in subdirectories of one directory.

Given that you are going to touch so many files, you could choose to process the files rather than simply moving them. For example, putting the contents of several files into a smaller number of files. You could also consider Zipping the files because this would cost you less to scan (Athena is charged based upon data read from disk -- zip files read less data and therefore cost less).

See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

This type of processing could be done efficiently on an Amazon EMR cluster that runs Hadoop, but some specialist knowledge is required to run Hadoop so it might be easier to use the coding with which you are familiar (eg Python).

Comment: did not really answer my question, by the zip is a nice idea.